# Drop Down Hamburger Menu Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, scroll

I ve created a drop down navigation menu with the famous hamburger icon. It drops down perfectly when the page is loaded and/or before scrolling the page down, but if I do scroll down and then scroll back up, when I click on the icon it cuts the nav ul lists in half, not showing anymore what it did before the scrolling.
I am not sure why it does that.

This is the script:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function (){
  $('.nav-btn').on("click", function() {
    $('#main-nav').slideToggle("slow");
     $(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() > 600) {
            $("#main-nav").removeAttr("style");
            }
        });
    });
    });
</script>
```

This is the HTML (inside the header):

```
<span class="nav-btn"></span>
    <nav id="main-nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home" class="scroll">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about" class="scroll">ABOUT</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portfolio" class="scroll">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact" class="scroll">CONTACT</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

This is the CSS:

```
#main-nav {
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
}

#main-nav li {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 5px #565656 solid;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

#main-nav li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}

#main-nav ul li {
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: 'montserratregular';
    text-align: left;
}

.nav-btn {
    display: block;
    background-color: #F1F1F1;
    color: #333;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-btn:before {
    content: url("hamburger.png");
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can have something to look at and play around with to help you better.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Alex81/4fzn0gdm/

Comment: not sure this is going to be any clearer though...

Comment: a couple of notes: 

1.) you can't resource jquery that way in jsfiddle. you need to select jquery from the dropdown in the top left corner under "frameworks & extensions".

2.) you don't need the <script> tags in the javascript section.

I was able to get the menu to expand and contract but I was not able to see the issue you are having. Without a replication of the issue you are experiencing it makes it extremely difficult to see what is being done wrong. Try to replicate it in that jsfiddle or if you have a live version send the link. Sorry I couldn't assist more without it.

Comment: Hi Matthew. is it better like this: https://jsfiddle.net/Alex81/4fzn0gdm/

Comment: FYI the link of the website is alessandro-dandrea.com. thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's what I needed! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a javascript that is applying a height of 130px on the #headwrapper div.

```
<div id="headwrapper" class="" style="height: 130px;">
```

When i take that 130px off the menu acts normally. it seems to be adding it onscroll though so when i scroll back up to the top the javascript enables it again. try changing that to `height: auto` or instead of setting a fixed height try setting it as a `height: auto; max-height: 1000px;` or something like that. this should take care of the issue you are having.

EDIT*: instead of changing the height inline like you have, i would suggest to put a `max-height: 75px;` on your `.small` and adding a `height: auto; max-height: 1000px;` on your `#headwrapper`. if you use this with a css-transition it should give you the same effect you have now.

Comment: Hi Matthew - where exactly did you see this height? Couldn't find it in the CSS. Which javascript are you referring to?

Comment: This is being applied from your `scroll.js` file.

Comment: Also just a little advice, in your `ga.js` file you should remove your `<script></script>` tags. you do not need these in a `.js` file. you only need these if you are writing your javascript directly in your html file.

Comment: Hi Matthew, it worked fine by changing the 130px with height: 'auto'; max-height: '1000px' within the scroll.js file as you suggested. thanks a lot!

Comment: No problem @Alessandro! Glad i could help! Another tid bit before i go, i noticed you have jquery referenced twice. Sometimes that can cause conflicts with your jquery. I suggest removing one of them to prevent issues down the road.

Comment: thanks a lot for you tips Matthew, I really appreciate it. Which jquery is referenced twice exactly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96613/discussion-between-alessandro-and-matthew).